# How do I make Helm chart Hooks post-install work if other charts are in running state

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a couple of helm charts in a `myapp/templates/` directory, and they deploy as expected with `helm install myapp`.

These two templates are for example:

- database.yaml
- cronjob.yaml

I'd like for the `cronjob.yaml` to only run after the `database.yaml` is in a running state.  I currently have an issue where `database.yaml` fairly regularly fails in a way we half expect (it's not ideal, but it is what it is).

I've found hooks, but I think I'm either using them incorrectly, or they don't determine whether the pod is in Running, Pending, some state of crashed, etc...

There are no changes I've made to database.yaml in order to use hooks, but my cronjob.yaml which I only want to run if database.yaml is in a running state, I added the annotations as follows:

**cronjob.yaml**

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: database
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "post-install"
  labels:
    app: database
    service: database
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: customtask
              image: "{{ .Values.myimage }}"
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - supercooltask.sh
          restartPolicy: Never
```

How can I change this hook configuration to allow `cronjob.yaml` to only run if `database.yaml` deploys and runs successfully?

Comment: What would happen if you unconditionally installed the CronJob, and it happened to run before the database was ready?  The generated Job would fail, but would anything else bad happen?

Comment: Perfectly valid solution normally, but my issue is that sometimes the database fails to exit its pending state, and when that happens, the cronjob does the same thing.  And then I have what's basically a loop that creates pending state pods every x amount of time.

Comment: @trueCamelType Have u tried using hook weights or Restart policy for jobs. Init containers can be used in the cron job template to wait for DB to be initialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use init containers in the Pod Spec of Cron Job to check DB is up and running.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#podspec-v1-core

Example:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
        ..
      containers:
        ..
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using that.  Any advice on how to check if that other containers status is Running?

Comment: Two way we can check it. 
1)DB Container is up using KubeAPIs(programmatically via CoreV1Api or direct API call using curl with label selector.
2)DB connection check using respective DB native health check commands